# Why can you add equations to solve for one variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have two unknowns and two equations:

$$x+2v+5+3x^2 = 0$$
$$2x-2v+5=0$$

why is it correct to simply add the two equations to get rid of v and to solve for x?

I understand that since both equations are equal to zero, I can write: x+2v+5+3x^2 =2x-2v+5
but this would not be the same as adding the two equations.

Comment: If $a=b$ and $c=d$ if must be true that $a+c=b+d$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition is a well-defined operation: if $r=t$ and $s=u$ then $r+s=t+u$.

For the first equation substituting $x+2v+5+3x^2=r$, $0=t$, and for the second equation substituting $2x-2v+5=s$, and $0=v$, we know that the equations $r=t$ and $s=u$ are true, so we may conclude that $r+s=t+u$ is true.

Now substitute back.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to add the two equations since $0+0=0.$